# how to change tree panel property "text:" with any other name e.g "name:" in extjs

Tags: extjs4

I am new in Extjs, following is my code:

```js
children: [{
    text:'Basic Ext Layouts',
    expanded: false,
    children:[{
        text:'Absolute',
        id:'absolute',
        leaf:true,
    },{
```

I was trying to make it like

```js
children: [{
    name:'Basic Ext Layouts',
    expanded: false,
    children:[{
        name:'Absolute',
        id:'absolute',
        leaf:true,
    },{
```

but its not working, please tell me solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set [displayField](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-cfg-displayField) config to `'name'`:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
  displayField: 'name',
  // ...
});
```

UPDATE

You also have to create Model for your treestore and append 'name' to it's fields config:

```js
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 'name' ]
});
```

Here is [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/gRWxQ/).

Comment: @user1225531, yes. That is because model is required for such configuration. Updated my answer.

Comment: can we do it for children: [{..too, if we need to change the parameter children to any other text?

Comment: @user1225531, yes. [Answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394507/how-to-change-name-of-json-key/9396551#9396551)