# How to change name of JSON key?

Tags: json, extjs

```
children: [
{
    name:'Basic Ext Layouts',
    expanded: false,
    children:[
    {
        name:'Absolute',
        id:'absolute',
        leaf:true,
    },{
        ...
    }]
}]
```

Is it possible to change `children` to `mydata`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON format is merely a String in javascript's point of view. So you could manipulate the JSON string with associated method.
JSON.

```
// The original
obj = {
  children: [
    {
        name:'Basic Ext Layouts',
        expanded: false,
        children:[
        {
            name:'Absolute',
            id:'absolute',
            leaf:true,
        }]
    }]
}

// Transfer the object to a JSON string
var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(obj);

// HERE you do the transform
var new_jsonstr = jsonstr.replace('"children"', '"mydata"');

// You probably want to parse the altered string later
var new_obj = JSON.parse(new_jsonstr);
```

Comment: If the data contains the string "children" for some reason, this could have horrible consecuences. At least a regex should be employed

Comment: Thanks. Serious problem here. I updated with an replacement '"children"' here to zero in on the JSON key only instead of a normal string. The only exception will be a normal string "children" here which should be aware of.

Comment: @JuanMendes I know its hack as I couldn't come up with more elegant solutions.

Comment: Offering a hack is fine. It's just weird that this was selected as the right answer when Edgar Villegas explained how this solution fails.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to change children to mydata?

Yes. Setup treestore's proxy to use reader with `root` config set to `'mydata'`:

```js
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'MyModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'mydata' // << this is required
        }
    },
    root: {
        myData: [
        {
           name:'Basic Ext Layouts',
```

Here is [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/JBf8j/).

Comment: I would like add json from outside, i dont want it in same file, as per specified in working example.